# Casting the same code in Objective-C gives another numerical result

Tags: objective-c, swift, nslog

### EDIT AND SOLUTION:

I realised just after asking the question: Xcode had automatically changed my code to cast to (long) in my `NSLog` ! That was why I was getting a different result !

---

#### Swift

```
let nowMillis = 1000 * self.timeIntervalSince1970
print(nowMillis)
```

`nowMillis` is: 1461865916801.75

#### Objective-C

```
double nowMillis = 1000 * [self timeIntervalSince1970];
NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)nowMillis]);
```

`nowMillis` is: -2147483648

`self` is `NSDate *now = [[NSDate alloc] init];` in both cases.

Comment: You are casting the objective c one to a long and the other is being printed out as a double. I think this is where the discrepancy comes in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not that the code produces a different result, but that you are printing it differently. Your Objective-C tries to convert `double` to `long`, but the value overflows.

If you print it without the conversion, you should get the same result:

```
double nowMillis = 1000 * [self timeIntervalSince1970];
NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", nowMillis]);
```

Comment: Thx, I just realized it after asking the question. But thx for the answer !